# Setting `scroll-snap-type` and `scroll-snap-align` to `none` on a mobile sized breakpoint doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, custom-scrolling

I can't seem to set `scroll-snap-type` to `none` on a mobile breakpoint. Ideally, I'd like to remove css scroll snap on mobile devices because it has been confusing for many users when scrolling through my application on mobile devices and can be wonky sometimes. CSS scroll snap works great, but I can't seem to set it to `none` for mobile devices.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Here is my code for CSS Scroll Snap:

```
section {
  display: flex;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
}

/* Mobile breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .description {
    width: 90%;
  }

  /* Parent set to none */
  .container {
    scroll-snap-type: none;
  }
  
  /* Child set to none */
  section {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you certain that max-width is enough?  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thank you for this great resource. When you say, "max-width is enough"? Are you referring to just the breakpoint I've specified as the only one for mobile devices not being enough? If so, this is just posed as an example. The addition of many other breakpoints for mobile devices is separate from the question I've asked.

Comment: Yes the break point you used in your example seems small for most modern phones.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game here, but reasonable juggling between mobile-first and desktop-first is often the best solution. Why not make sure even the latest mobiles don't snap and apply the snapping from let's say 600px and up?

So, do this instead. Then you don't have to default/null already given values.

```
/* Tablet and Desktop and up breakpoint */
@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```